# How to lazy load Facebook's Like Box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I have found a [tutorial for lazy loading Facebook's like box](http://cyrilmazur.com/2011/08/deferred-lazy-loading-facebook-widgets.html), but it's appropriate only if you use one FB widget on a page.

How would it look like if you want to load "like button" normally, but would like to lazy load "like box", i. e. load it only if the user scrolls and like box is in the viewport?

Also, is it possible to do it without any plugins nad possibly without jquery, i. e. using only pure javascript?

Here is the mentioned code:

```
/** 
* check if facebookHolder is in viewport, and then load Like Box widget 
*/ 
$(document).ready(function() { 
function checkScrollingForWidget(event) { 
    $('#facebookHolder:in-viewport').each(function() { 
    $('#facebookHolder').append('<div id="fb-root"></div>'); 
    $('#facebookHolder').append('<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/forexagone" width="300" show_faces="true" stream="false" header="false"></fb:like-box>'); 

    jQuery.getScript('http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1', function() { 
        FB.init({status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true}); 
    }); 

    $(window).unbind('scroll', checkScrollingForWidget); 
} 

$(window).bind('scroll', checkScrollingForWidget); 
});
```

Since Facebook's like box is so widely used and can slow down page loading a bit (even if it's async.), I was quite surprised to see that there are no newer tutorials how to do this. Is it possible at all?

Thank you in advance for your ideas.

This is Markus' code in a simple HTML document:

```
    <html><head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>Lazy Load</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.appelsiini.net/download/jquery.viewport.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


  <style type="text/css">
    .facebookHolder {
    height: 50px;
    background: #ccc;
}
  </style>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.getScript('http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1', function() {
        // initiate like boxed already in viewport as soon as fb sdk loaded.
        checkScrollingForWidget();
    });

    function checkScrollingForWidget(event) { 
        $('.facebookHolder:in-viewport').each(function(index, item) {
            if (!$(item).hasClass('fb_loaded')) {
                $(item).append('<fb:like-box href="' + $(item).attr('data-url') + '" width="300" show_faces="true" stream="false" header="false"></fb:like-box>');
                $(item).addClass('fb_loaded');
                FB.XFBML.parse();
            }
        }); 
    }

    $(window).bind('scroll', checkScrollingForWidget); 
});
</script>


</head>
<body>


<div id="fb-root"></div>

<div class="facebookHolder" data-url="https://www.facebook.com/Google"></div>
<p style="height: 500px;"></p>
<div class="facebookHolder" data-url="https://www.facebook.com/yahoo"></div>
<p style="height: 500px;"></p>
<div class="facebookHolder" data-url="https://www.facebook.com/stackoverflowpage"></div>


</body></html>
```

Comment: `:in-viewport` is no native jquery. Have you imported the corrsponding plugin correctly?

Answer (score 3):

This could be inteteresting for me too so I just fixed the tutorial script:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Kme2/)

Of course you need to import jquery and the viewport plugin (if you want to use it).

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.viewport.js"></script>
```

Then include fbroot tag only once and give the holders an specific data-url attribute because loading one url multiple times doesn't seem to be possible. Late we will read out this data-attribute.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<div class="facebookHolder" data-url="https://www.facebook.com/Google"></div>
<p style="height: 500px;"></p>
<div class="facebookHolder" data-url="https://www.facebook.com/yahoo"></div>
<p style="height: 500px;"></p>
<div class="facebookHolder" data-url="https://www.facebook.com/stackoverflowpage"></div>
```

Then use the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.getScript('http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1', function() {
        // initiate like boxed already in viewport as soon as fb sdk loaded.
        checkScrollingForWidget();
    });

    function checkScrollingForWidget(event) { 
        $('.facebookHolder:in-viewport').each(function(index, item) {
            if (!$(item).hasClass('fb_loaded')) {
                $(item).append('<fb:like-box href="' + $(item).attr('data-url') + '" width="300" show_faces="true" stream="false" header="false"></fb:like-box>');
                $(item).addClass('fb_loaded');
                FB.XFBML.parse();
            }
        }); 
    }

    $(window).bind('scroll', checkScrollingForWidget); 
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Although it works perfectly in a fiddle, it won't work in production. Is it possible that it's also due to a conflict with like buttons? I have multiple like button on a page and this like box. I only want the like box to be lazy loaded. Also, what about including JavaScript SDK? Your code already has it all, right?

Comment: I am now trying to make your code work in a simple HTML document. It does load all of the boxes, but at the same time, i. e. the 2nd and 3rd one are not lazy loaded, although they are not in the viewport initially. Could you check what's wrong in the code above?

Comment: Also, after a while, if you're not active in the browser on that page, boxes simply disappear (iFrame's width and height parameters turn to 0).

Comment: The code initiated the sdk each time a likebox is appended which may cause the problems. I updated my answer taking Kalmi's answer into account.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing has changed. It still loads everything at the page load and boxes disappear after a while. Could you test the simple page that I have pasted in the question description? It's your code implemented in a basic HTML page.

Comment: I dont know if some other parts of you code interfere with it but the fiddle is working so basicly everythin is fine.

Comment: Strange, this second version works in production, but not on localhost. However, it still disappears after a while and it doesn't work if you click on a link and go back in the browser (when you go back and the same part of the page is now in the viewport).

Answer (score 3):

You can add a Facebook widget any time dynamically, but you need call [FB.XFBML.parse](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) after adding it to the DOM.